# Symbolic Link limit - Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista

I am trying to test the 31 reparse point limit mentioned for Symbolic link in Windows Vista. But I could not reproduce by any of following listed cases. Can someone guide?

1. Created 36 symlinks in a directory c:\temp\testlink for a executable residing in c:\temp\testlink.
2. Created 36 symlinks in a directory c:\temp\testlink to 36 different executables residing in c:\temp\testlink.
3. Created 36 symlinks in a directory c:\temp1 for 36 different executables residing in c:\temp\testlink.

How does this limit act in Windows 7 and 2008?

-Karthik

Comment: Are you creating virus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit refers to the number of reparse points that Windows can follow when evaluating a single path. For instance, C:\a\b\c\d\e can have up to five reparse points (you may have to forgive any off-by-one errors), one for each directory level in the path.

I don't believe there is any specific limit on how many reparse points a directory can have.

Comment: For those who want to check, take a look at ObpLookupObjectName in the kernel.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, 

thanks for your reply. I tried creating a link to a file existing in c:\temp\1\2\3\..\32 and it got succeeded in Vista. Am I doing anything wrong here?

-Karthik

Comment: That path is only going through a single reparse point. The limit applies when 1 is a reparse point to a directory containing 2, which is another reparse point containing 3, which is ... I hope you get the drift.

Comment: In other words it's talking about a chain of symlinks.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. That was useful and I simulated the behavior by following approach:

In "c:\temp" created following directories:

 1\1.lnk <SYMBOLIC LINK> 2\2.lnk <SYMBOLIC LINK> 3\3.lnk <SYMBOLIC LINK> .......31\31.lnk <SYMBOLIC LINK> 32

In directory 32, I copied a file test.dll.

Now when I create a symbolic link to test.dll residing in directory 32 as 'mklink c:\temp\testtarget.dll c:\temp\1\1.lnk\test.dll' this failed to work properly. This has to go through 32 reparsing points to get the test.dll. 

Hope what I did is right.